# Convert VARCHAR(MAX) to file (pdf)

Tags: vb.net

In the last two days I've been puzzling with a error that cannot identify. I confess I'm not a experienced User on Visual Basic 2010.  I've been searching this and on other sites to try to understand the reason of this error, but with so much information sometimes I get a bit confused.

I have a database with an uploaded pdf's on a field called `contentx VARCHAR(MAX)` and need to convert it back to pdf file. When I run the program it gives me the following error:

Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `System.Byte[]` - on the line regarding `dbbyte = dt.Rows(0)("contentx")`

This is the program:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim FS As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim dbbyte As Byte()

    Connect.Close()
    Connect.Open()
    cmd = Connect.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Filename, extension, contentx FROM tbldocument where seq=1"
    'reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    'reader.Close()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Connect.Close()

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'Get a stored PDF bytes
        dbbyte = dt.Rows(0)("contentx")
        'System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dt.Rows[0]("contentx").ToString ());
        'store file Temporarily 
        Dim filepath As String = "c:\temp.pdf"
        'Assign File path create file
        FS = New FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        'Write bytes to create file
        FS.Write(dbbyte, 0, dbbyte.Length)
        'Close FileStream instance
        FS.Close()
        ' Open file after write 
        'Create instance for process class
        Dim Proc As New Process()
        'assign file path for process
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = filepath
        Proc.Start()
    End If
```

I also confess I'm a bit confused about `byte` and `byte()` types, and I believe I'm almost there.

Comment: so `contentx` is a string in the DB but you want it as a byte array? just use `dbbyte  = System.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dt.Rows(0)("contentx"))`

Comment: yes content is a varchar(max) field from a converted pdf file to SQL. I just want to convert it back to pdf file again when the user wants to view the pdf. Your tip worked!!!! thanks a Lot!!!

Comment: cool, i'll make it an answer.

Comment: Now I have a damage pdf and cannot be viewed I believe is due to a wrong encoding

Comment: Well there are various encoding types you can use: ASCII, UTF8, Unicode..

Answer (score 0):

so `contentx` is a string in the DB but you want it as a byte array? just use:

```
dbbyte  = System.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dt.Rows(0)("contentx"))
```

This should work now.

Maybe you should look into storing the pdf as `VARBINARY(MAX)`.